# How to pass a random function as an argument?

Tags: python, function, random, arguments

Python is so flexible, that I can use functions as elements of lists or arguments of other functions. For example:

```
x = [sin, cos]
y = s[0](3.14) # It returns sin(3.14)
```

or

```
def func(f1, f2):
   return f1(2.0) + f2(3.0)
```

However, it is not clear to me how to do the same with random functions. For example I want to use Gaussian distributions: `[random.normalvariate(3.0, 2.0), random.normalvariate(1.0, 4.0)]`. In this example I will get a fixed list containing two elements. But what I want to get, is a list with random elements. What is a good way to do it in python?

Comment: couldn't understand properly, are you looking for variable number of arguments ? http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it with [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) functions:

```
[lambda: random.normalvariate(3.0, 2.0), lambda: random.normalvariate(1.0, 4.0)]
```

You see the difference with parentheses. `sin` is a function, `sin(x)` is the return value of this function. As you cannot create a function without parentheses representing `random.normalvariate(1.0, 4.0)`, you have to define it as a lambda function.

Answer (score 7):

Use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or `lambda`

Those are basically the same:

```
[lambda: normalvariate(3, 2), ...]
# or
[partial(normalvariate, 3, 2), ...]
```

They are both equivalent to:

```
def _function():
    return normalvariate(3, 2)

[_function, ...]
```

`partial` is more flexible, gives you much better control over creation of `_function` and lets you avoid lambda syntax clutter.

By the way, there were some controversions over lambda in the Python community, but in the end Guido admitted that [finding a superior alternative to the lambda expression is "an impossible quest."](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2007/06/guido-van-rossum-comments-on-status-of-python-3-0/)

Answer (score 5):

You should use partial from functools:

```
import functools
arg_sets = [(3.0, 2.0), (1.0, 4.0)]
myfuncs = [functools.partial(random.normalvariate, *args) for args in arg_sets]
myfuncs[0]()
```